# WP Content Not Loading in Editor

Tags: wordpress, content-editor

Content is not loading in the content editor on the admin side. It is working in one location and not working in another location. Please check the below image of the content editor section.

[image]

Comment: check under text tab

Answer (score 0):

There is a common error that occurs in the WordPress editor, where the text color is reset to white and the buttons needed to make changes on your editor in WordPress and its content go missing.

Simple options to fix the WordPress error

- Clear the browser cache
- Deactivate plugins

**Clear the browser cache**

*To clear cache from your Chrome browser:*

- Open the browser and click on a button with three dots at the top
  right corner of the browser window.
- Place the mouse pointer on ‘More tools’ and click on ‘Clear browsing
  data’.
- Select a time range from the dropdown and click the ‘clear data’
  button.

*To clear cache from your Mozilla Firefox browser:*

- Open the browser and click on the menu button at the upper right
  corner.
- Select Options from the menu.
- In the Privacy section, click on Clear your recent history. From the
  drop-down menu next to a Time range to clear, select Everything, then
  click on Clear Now.

Hopefully, one of the above-mentioned solutions helped you fix WordPress issue and revert your text editor to its normal state. However, if you are still unable to fix it feel free to contact.

Comment: Thanks for your response Navnish, I have tried deactivating plugins, tried accessing page in private window in two browsers (FF and Chrome), added this line in define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS',false); in wp-config.php also. Still its not working.

Comment: have you tried switching to text editor? Is that shows content?

Comment: Yes, I tried both visual editor and code editor, not working in either case.

Comment: Thats creepy... Can you try installing Tiny MCE plugin may be that works or Classic Editor plugin? I think give a try to these may be it can be resolved. If not don't loose hope, will try to figure-out something else

Comment: I found really weird result after trying out commenting tinymce init and un-commenting it.  
Content get loads if edit page is refreshed with 'Text' edit option selected for tinymce content editor and content remains there if I switch to 'Visual'. But if page is refreshed with 'Visual' option is selected content does not load in both 'Visual' and 'Text' options. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Actually its very hard to tell without checking out exact code and everything. Is this website old? or recently built this?